# How to transform textfield data to uppercase while user is typing within the field?

Tags: jquery, html

There is a textfield : `<input type="text" id="id" name="name" value="value" />`

How to make any entered data to be in uppercase while it is typing ?

Comment: `keypress` or `keyUp` or `keyDown` event...

Comment: Why not use css `text-transform:uppercase` for this? Or is that not what you want?

Comment: Gee, so many answers, and none that work when pasting something with the mouse.

Comment: @MrLister lolz.. yeah. didn't think about it :). Hey `text-transform : uppercase;` does  that.

Comment: Do you mean *any* entered data? Should ä, é, þ, α, я etc. be uppercased, too? Should they appear in uppercase to the user, or in the DOM and submitted data, or both?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use `keyup()` and `toUpperCase()`..

```
$('#id').keyup(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

or using DOMelement

```
$('#id').keyup(function(){
 this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

or using just CSS (no javascript at all)

```
 #id{
    text-transform:uppercase;
 }
```

[using CSS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/YeU7F/1/)

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/YeU7F/)

Comment: how to find these fiddle ? or how to create them ?

Comment: Almost posted a nearly identical solution :P... I'm too slow this morning.

Comment: @pheromix... click the link that i posted in my answer..it will take you to jsfiddle .. you can create your own there..

Comment: I want to know how to create fiddles ?

Comment: google it `usign creating jsfiddle`.. there are lots of tutorials... i got one here http://cavica.com/using-jsfiddle-to-write-better-javascript/

Comment: I recomend the this.SelectionStart and this.SelectionEnd to control position, else when you press arrow-back key you never can back in the value of the textbox

Answer (score 3):

Please call this function on your input "onkeydown" action

```
<input type="text" id="id" name="name" value="value" onkeydown="makeUppercase()" />
    function makeUppercase() {
    document.form_name.name.value = document.form_name.name.value.toUpperCase();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$('#id').keyup(function(){
  $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Or

```
var inputField = document.getElementById('id');
inputField.onkeyup = function(){
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

would it not be easier to simply set a css rule to text-transform to lowercase, and then on submission lowercase the JS or server side lower case the string?

```
textarea{    
    text-transform:lowercase;    
}
```

[CSS text-transform fiddle (with JS lowercase)](http://jsfiddle.net/biznuge/8b8Gd/5/)

Doing it with JS is likely to make the browser work harder the longer the string gets.

Comment: Just realised this is doing lowercase, but just swap em artound to make it work as expected. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<input type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase">
```

[Demo - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oneofthelions/z45ygobL/)

Comment: This will only display as an uppercase text. But if the form is submitted - it will still be sent the same letter-case as the user typed.

Comment: @CristiC The user didn't say submit the text, the user only wants the text to be displayed in uppercase.

Answer (score -1):

A different approach: (*just now tried, working fine*)

```
$('.result').keydown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.value += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
});
```